# Replace dictionary value list with average

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary, say `mydict`, like this:

```
key1: list1
key2: list2
key3: list3
```

what is the pythonic way of replacing the lists (values) with their averages (avoiding for loops)?

Comment: Your list is not a list of `int` or `float`? Show some sample data please.

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3 you can import `mean` from `statistics` and use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> d = {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':[7,8,9]}
>>> d = {k:mean(v) for k,v in d.items()}
>>> d
{'a': 2.0, 'c': 8.0, 'b': 5.0}
```

Answer (score 4):

use python [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

```
>>> mydict = {'a':[1.0, 2.0], 'b':[3.0, 4.0]}
>>> mydict = {k:float(sum(v))/len(v) for k, v in mydict.items()}
>>> mydict
{'a': 1.5, 'b': 3.5}
```